# Import Large CSV files into SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv

I want to import data from a csv file into SQL Server through C#. CSV file has over 2000 columns when converted.

What is the best way to approach this?

It's going to be an ongoing process and I am looking to perform CRUD operations.

I tried converting csv into datatable and used SQLBulkCopy to insert which seems to work for me. I am confused on how to structure the SQL table, since there is a limit of 1024 columns.

Comment: You mentioned SqlBulkCopy worked fine for you, did it work fine with 2000 columns?

Comment: The problem is when saving it to the SQL table. It throws me an exception of having more than 1024 columns.

Comment: You can split your Table into two tables of 1000 columns each, related by common primary key value.  In C# side as well split your datatable into two.

Comment: Similar question may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54658240/import-csv-file-with-more-than-1024-columns-into-new-sql-server-table

Comment: @AmitKumar I ended up doing that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can split your Table into two tables of 1000 columns each, related by common primary key value. In `C#` side as well split your datatable into two.